# react childNodes do not have offsetWidth according to typescript. How can I please typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Something as simple as this. Consider this `div HTMLElement`

```
<div>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>am</span>
  <span>here</span>
</div>
```

I can pass that element into a function and do some simple math on it and it's children. `parentDiv` is the `div` mentioned above:

```
const wrapperWidth = parentDiv.offsetWidth; // no type error, I get the correct width
parentDiv.childNodes.forEach((elm) => {
  console.log(elm.offsetWidth) //ts is yelling at me here, even though I do get width and there is no error
});
```

Here ts has an aneurysm and claims that my elements (`elm` of type `ChildNode`) do not have an `offsetWidth`, but I am infactt receiving the width and the correct ones. This goes the same if I try to do something as `parentDiv.children` or any other means of listing the children.

How can I please typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) include elements, text and comments. But the elements in the `div` element are all `span` element. There are not text and comments nodes. So you may want to use [Element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children), `Element.children` includes only element nodes.

```
const parentDiv = document.createElement('div');

const elementNodes = Array.from(parentDiv.children);
elementNodes.forEach((elm) => {
  if (elm instanceof HTMLElement) {
    console.log(elm.offsetWidth);
  }
});
```

The type of `elm` is `Element`, and `Element` have no property `offsetWidth`. You likely expect it to return an `HTMLElement`, but this is not obvious to the compiler because it could just as well be an `SVGElement`.

You can use [`instanceof` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) to narrow the type of `elm` to `HTMLElement`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQwE4FMxQCIEsBuMC8MAJiMAK4C2aUAdMKglCgKIA2KV6AFAORG48AlAG4AsACgJoSLBTtOUAHIgiKCARgBBJEgQBPGgDMkICl0Sp02HHQAWWVkUsiJcjtWWqIRkEmYJgWy4uOQpBAgA+GABvCRgYLEMYENYKBJkEMGAUECSACQAVAFkAGTZ3dHDY8Xj46QgQdhpWEABzFIoaXMMIFCgAdSwiKFsXGpgAXwkJkSA)